# Why does `less` consume so much CPU with a reasonably sized file, fast disk and plenty of memory?

Tags: regular-expression, less, cpu-usage, slowdown

There seems to be a pathological case with one of the files I'm reading with `less`.
The file is ~300MB in size, disk is fast (local NMVE) and the file can comfortably fit in memory, there is no swapping or anything like that.

`less --version` gives me

```
less 563 (PCRE regular expressions)
```

on Arch Linux. I run with no commandline parameters (no `-R` or `-S`).
The file I am reading is being written to.

**Usage:**
I notice using `follow` (pressing `F`) is generally slow for this file, but workable.
Things are made worse by having a search active (for highlighting) while `follow` is in progress.
Now if I search for the following: `(something|something-else).*|.*warn` and then hit `F (follow)`, it totally grinds to a halt. I need to kill it from a different terminal.

I've been using such regexes with much larger files with no issue. Could something be amiss?

**Edit**: more exact steps and info:

- happens with 50MB file, no long lines
- another process appends to the file every 15s

Steps:

- I open the file, go to end (Shift+g)
- search for `(something|something-else).*|.*warn` (says `Pattern not found` since at the end)
- follow (Shift+f) -> CPU goes to 100% and seemingly never stops
- instead of pressing Shift+f, the same happens if I press UpArrow following the search
- if I reduce the regex to one of its parts (either `(something|something-else).*` or `.*warn` the operations take a few seconds, still slow but manageable
- resident memory shows as 400MB in htop
- **Ctrl+C doesn't work to interrupt it, need to kill from outside**

Comment: About that regular expression, do you still have the same issue if you remove the two instances of `.*` (which does not seem to be necessary for actually matching)?

Comment: Are their newlines in the file or is it one big 300MB-line?

Comment: It's a log file, there are some long lines but not exceptionally long. I just tried again and the issue is there, adding precise steps on how it reproduces for me.

Comment: Why do you need `.*`?

Comment: it's mostly for the highlighting, tbh. Highlighting starts from the beginning so I can quickly tell what's what